# Mutliple server with same mysql datadir using SAN?

Tags: mysql, linux, san

Let us assume creating Lun in SAN for MySQL datadir. Can we present the LUN into 3 host servers(using same mysql datadir in 3 host servers). Assume host1 will be used for write and other hosts for read.

Answer (score 0):

Running several servers on the same data directory is dangerous if not impossible. The usual solution for scaling out would be to set up a master-slave replication.

http://top-performance.blogspot.de/2012/03/how-to-setup-mysql-replication-in-11.html

Comment: Hi Micheal ! Iam looking for Mysql running on multiple host using SAN.